# Подключение стилей к окну WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, style

Сейчас подключаю стили к окну вот так:

```
<Window
    x:Class="BrainTrain.Windows.WorkWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BrainTrain.Windows"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WorkWindow"
    Height="482">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
            <Setter
                Property="Stroke"
                Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Все отлично, но когда стилей будет больше, будет неудобно с ними работать. Из этого следует вопрос. Как подключить стили, вынесенные в отдельный файл? У меня он создан, а куда и что прописывать не пойму.

### Вот App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="BrainTrain.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="Localization/lang.xaml" /><!--Localization File-->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Вот путь относительный путь к файлу где хочу что бы были ресурсы.

```
ViewResources/WorkWindowStyles.xaml
```

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы откроете [документацию на MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries), то увидите, что `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` представляет собой `Collection<ResourceDictionary>` (то же самое можно увидеть, если поставить курсор на нужное слово и нажать <kbd>F12</kbd> в Visual Studio), значит вам нужно просто добавить все нужные словари ресурсов в эту коллекцию:

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Localization/lang.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewResources/WorkWindowStyles.xaml"/>
                <!--etc-->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Еще чтение по теме: [Объединенные словари ресурсов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/merged-resource-dictionaries)